# Use nvidia-docker instead of docker with Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to figure out how to use nvidia-docker (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) using https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html#docker-container.

**Problem**

My current Ansible playbook execute my container using "docker" command instead of "nvidia-docker".

**What I have done**

According to some readings, I have tried adding my devices, without success

`docker_container:
        name: testgpu
        image: "{{ image }}"
        devices: ['/dev/nvidiactl', '/dev/nvidia-uvm', '/dev/nvidia0', '/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools]
        state: started`

*note I tried different syntax for devices (inline ..), but still getting the same problem*

This command does not throws any error. As expected it creates a Docker container with my image and try to start it.

Looking at my container logs:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  No CUDA driver found`

which is the exact same error I'm getting when running
`docker run -it <image>`
instead of 
`nvidia-docker run -it <image>`

Any ideas how to override docker command when using docker_container with Ansible?

I can confirm my CUDA drivers are installed, and all the path /dev/nvidia* are valid.

Thanks

Comment: If you look closely, I already linked whatever you have said on my previous message. All your informations are on the first paragraph on the ansible doc about docker_container.

Answer (score 1):

`docker_container` module doesn't use `docker` executable, it uses Docker daemon API through docker-py Python library.

Looking at [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/blob/master/nvidia-docker) wrapper script, it sets `--runtime=nvidia` and `-e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.

To set `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` you can use `env` argument of `docker_container`.

But I see no ways to set `runtime` via `docker_container` module as of current Ansible 2.4.
You can try to overcome this by setting `"default-runtime": "nvidia"` in your `daemon.json` configuration file, so Docker daemon will use `nvidia` runtime by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried to make my own module based on docker_container, but ultimately it fails as `runtime` is an unexpected param for api/container.py. 
I also tried to override the default-runtime without success.
For now I' will just use Ansible's `command`, hopefully they will make "runtime" customizable in a new release